# Javascript metatag date compare and redirect

Tags: javascript, meta-tags

I am trying to read metatag expires before page loads and redirect to other url if its already expired without displaying this page.
My expire tag looks like this `<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="Tue, 21 Aug 2012 14:30:00 GMT">`

The way I have done my current date I dont think I can compare my meta tag date with it. 
Can some one tell me what I have to modify to make it to work. Thanks

```
<body onload="compareDate()"> 

function getExpiresContent() { 
   var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta'); 

   for (i=0; i<metas.length; i++) { 
      if (metas[i].getAttribute("property") == "Expires") { 
         return metas[i].getAttribute("content"); 
      } 
   } 

    return "";
}

function compareDate(){
   var expiresDateString = getExpiresContent();
   var expiresDate= new Date(expiresDateString);
   var currentDate = new Date();
   var day = currentDate.getDate();
   var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
   var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
   var today = ("<b>" + day + "/" + month + "/" + year + "</b>");

   if (expiresDate < today){
    window.navigate(”top.jsp”);
   }
}
```

Comment: If you are putting this in the ONLOAD event, the page has ALREADY LOADED. Use a JS block in the head instead.

Comment: From the head tag how do I call that function and can you tell me how can I format two dates so I can compare it right. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a script block in the HEAD if you want to catch this before page load. Put your functions in the script block then call your function immediately after:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function getExpiresContent() {
...
}

function compareDate() {
...
)

compareDate()
</script>
```

In order to compare dates, you need to grab the "expires" value and build a date object (not a string), then compare it to the current date.

See this excellent explanation of how the data object works:

http://www.elated.com/articles/working-with-dates/